# object HTMLTextAreaElement javascript response on document.write

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

Why can't I get var yourName to show in the text through Javascript/Jquery? With all the things I've tried, it gives me [object HTMLTextAreaElement] as a response. What am I doing wrong?

**Javascript:**

```
var yourName = window.prompt("please enter name")
```

**HTML + Javascript:**

```
<div id="info"><p>
<script>document.write(yourName)</script>, your job is...
</p><div>
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/fbt4rjjt/

Comment: I've also tried `<script>document.write(yourName.value)</script>` as recommended [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=object+HTMLTextAreaElement+javascript+response).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not PHP it won't render your html "in place". You have to create a "container" and then for example change its **innerHTML**.

You can achieve it for example in this way:

HTML:

```
    <div id="info"><p>
        <b id="thename"></b>, your job is...
    <div>
```

JS:

```
    var yourName = window.prompt("please enter name") 
    document.getElementById("thename").innerHTML = yourName
```

check out this here: https://jsfiddle.net/cqv8jfgj/